# Prestashop admin error

Tags: jquery, prestashop, jquery-lint

I'm getting below error at Firebug console at the moment:

```
attr(id) special check failed
jquery.lint.js (line 99)
More info:
Insted of accessing the property via attr(id), use undefined insted
Collection: [input.button Change✉]
Location:
@http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js:16 @http://www.antoineandstanley.com/js/admin.js:401
```

What could this mean?

Comment: Actually the output is from [jquery lint](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-lint/) so I'm re-tagging the question

Comment: Can you tell me what version of Prestashop are you using?